# Multiple Filter on array nested angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this model:

```
<ArrayOfContactList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/test.Controllers">
<ContactList>
<Acquisition>2019-01-01T00:00:00</Acquisition>
<AddModCode>00000</AddModCode>
<Address/>
<AssistanceDeadline>2019-01-01T00:00:00</AssistanceDeadline>
<City i:nil="true"/>
<ContactID>134</ContactID>
<ContactStateID>2</ContactStateID>
<ContactTypeID>1</ContactTypeID>
<License>000000</License>
<NCalls>1</NCalls>
<Name>Test Name</Name>
<Note>NOTE</Note>
<PIva>xxxxxxxx</PIva>
<ProductDesc>Product Desc</ProductDesc>
<ProductID>1</ProductID>
<Referents xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/test.Models">
      <d3p1:Referent>
      <d3p1:Contact i:nil="true"/>
      <d3p1:ContactID>134</d3p1:ContactID>
      <d3p1:Email>email@email.it</d3p1:Email>
      <d3p1:LastName>LAST NAME</d3p1:LastName>
      <d3p1:Name>NAME</d3p1:Name>
      <d3p1:Note>NOTE</d3p1:Note>
      <d3p1:Phone>PHONE</d3p1:Phone>
      <d3p1:ReferentID>19</d3p1:ReferentID>
      <d3p1:Title i:nil="true"/>
      </d3p1:Referent>
</Referents>
<StateDesc>STATE DESC</StateDesc>
<TypeDesc>TYPE DESC</TypeDesc>
<Warning i:nil="true"/>
<WebApplication>WEB APPLICATION</WebApplication>
</ContactList>
```

I would like to filter inside a ContactList array by searching both for the ContactList properties and for the properties contained in the Referents array contained within it.

I have this:

```
this.contactService.getAll().subscribe(contacts => {                  
   this.allContacts = contacts;                    
   this.assignCopy();    
});
```

```
assignCopy(){
   this.filteredContacts = Object.assign([], this.allContacts);
}
```

```
this.filteredContacts = Object.assign([], this.allContacts).filter( item => {
    (item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) ||
    (item.License.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) ||
    (item.PIva.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) ||
    (item.Referents.some(i => {
      (i.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) ||
      (i.LastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1)
    }))
})
```

My problem is that this.filteredContacts is always empty even though it applies a valid filter.
Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are returning **nothing** from your filter callback, hence it evaluates to **false**, making an empty list. Try adding `return` slightly before `(item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1)`

Comment: I added ```return``` as you told me, but it doesn't work the same

Comment: Is `this.allContacts` filled properly? Can you please replicate the issue in a stackblitz?